# Message repeating even after explicitly checking for history in discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, replit

I'm trying to make a discord bot and I've added functionality of the tasks repeating after 24 hours using tasks.loop after at an interval of 24 hours( 64800 seconds). Since the code is run on repl.it, I've used uptime robot to continuously send a ping after 5 minutes to make it running always in the repl.it.
My issue is that even after checking `history`in the channel the message is getting send again as you can see in the below image. ( by checking here I mean the explanation which is the explanation that comes with the API). I'm using NASA api here.

Code snippet

```
def get_APOD():
   
   image = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key="+apod)
   json_data = json.loads(image.text)
   description = json_data["url"]
   explanation = "'" + json_data["explanation"]+ "'"
   title = json_data["title"]
   return  description,explanation,title

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 
 print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
 send_message.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=64800.0)  
async def send_message():
 channel = client.get_channel(int(apod_channel))
 messages = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()
 description,explanation,title = get_APOD() 
 if messages[0].content == explanation:
   print("Its the same")
 else:
   await channel.send(description)
   await channel.send(title)
   await channel.send(explanation)
```

[image: What's happening now]. Here you can see the messages repeating twice. It shouldn't by the code I've written here. Since it check for the history in the channel.

What is the issue here? Appreciate any help.

EDIT:  When I restart the repl.it IDE the code will run alright and print "It's the same" as it should if the message is already sent but otherwise it's failing.

Comment: What is your `get_APOD() ` function?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've edited and added it now.

Comment: the variable "apod" is the key and all that is working completely alright.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running the bot twice ? You could try to restart your PC/server and see if it stays like this.
You could try printing messages[0].content, and explaination to see if they hold exactly the same type (string) and value